# Android (Google Play) Referral Tracking Limitations

Tags: android, google-play, tracking, referrer

Using INSTALL_REFERRER and our own broadcast receiver, we are able to track installs for a referral program in our app. We are, however, running into certain limitations in the tracking process. Has anyone been able to solve andy of these issues?

1. When we share a campaign URL with another user, when the second user tries to open the URL, he will encounter two options for opening it, browser and Google Play. The referral tracking is done only if user installs the app through Google Play.
2. For older versions like 2.1, we were not able to capture the referral tracking. So if the second user has OS 2.1, the app does not track the installation.

Answer (score 3):

In order to load the referrer when sending the link to another user (and in order to avoid the browser/google-play question), the link should not be:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.appname&referrer=abc

but

> market://details?id=com.xxx.appname&referrer=abc