# Passing referrer to track installs Google Play browser mode

Tags: android, google-play, install-referrer

This question is similar to the one asked here
[Android (Google Play) Referral Tracking Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033313/android-google-play-referral-tracking-limitations) which hasnt recieved much attention.

I wish to send a deeplink url(as a referrer) and pass the same to the app once its installed.

People who have defaulted the http google play url to playstore on device or select google play app to launch the url forward the referrer but the same is **not done** if the browser launches the url and the user then selects install.

Is there a workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [App Invites API](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/) is exactly what you want.  It allows your users to send links to your application and it tracks referrers and deep link data.  It also works across Android and iOS.